# Cannot move GitKraken Window on Pop_Os(20.10)

Tags: gitkraken

When I start gitkraken, I cannot minimize, maximize or move the window.

I use Pop_Os 20.10.

Does anyone know this problem? Or does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Let me now, if you need further information.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  Happening to me on Windows 11 lol